# Python/Django excel to html

Tags: python, html, django, excel

Okay, so what I want to do is upload an excel sheet and display it on my website, in html. What are my options here ? I've found this xlrd module that allows you to read the data from spreadsheets, but I don't really need that right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you need xlrd? It sounds like exactly what you need.

Create a Django model with a FileField that holds the spreadsheet. Then your view uses xlrd to loop over the rows and columns and put them into an HTML table. Job done.

Possible complications: multiple sheets in one Excel file; formulas; styles.

Comment: xlrd may not be able to handle .xlsx (compressed) excel files natively.  Though, there may be some .xlsx => .xls conversion scripts floating around somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Zoho Viewer](http://viewer.zoho.com/home.do) in your template.
For example:

```
<iframe src="http://viewer.zoho.com/api/urlview.do?url=http://www.iasted.org/conferences/formatting/Presentations-Tips.ppt&embed=true"
        style="width:300px; height:300px;" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```